# Site Collection Administrators - Site design JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, json, site-design

I would like to add a group to my site design which will be Site Collection Administrators.

I used such code in JSON while creating design:

```
{
     "verb": "addPrincipalToSPGroup",
     "principal": "customgorup@scustomgroup",
     "group": "Owners"
},
```

I thought I would get this kind of result:

My user is a part of this group, so when I set my design, as a member of customgroup I will be able to edit the whole site.

During the data migration tests I get the information that I am not the administrator of the collection.

I do not understand this since my group is an owner which means full access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently adding user/group as **Site Collection Administrators** is not possible using Site design JSON.

> `addPrincipalToSPGroup` action currently only supports the Visitors (permission level: read), Members (permission level: contribute or edit, depending on the site template), and Owners (permission level: full control) groups.

**Source**: [Add users (principals) to SharePoint Groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#add-users-principals-to-sharepoint-groups)

---

Site owner & site collection administrator is not same entity. For more information, see [Understanding SharePoint Groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default-sharepoint-groups).

Comment: thanks, but I can't from Json add my custom group to the page as owner ? Example: I have group A and i want to give access for customGroup to do all what i need means full control ?

Comment: You can add users, security groups, or Microsoft 365 groups to "Owners" group. so that they will have "Full control" on SP site. However, I think if there are any item level permissions applied on list/library/pages/folder/items then these users will not have permissions on those. You might want to check if there are any item level permissions on your pages.

Comment: It seems to me that this owner group has too weak accesses and I have to map it well with active directory https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/understanding-permissions-when-migrating

Comment: Site Owners group have "Full Control" access on sites. have you tried mapping with AD like you mentioned? is it working for you?

Comment: I got a user from the administration to migrate data